# How can i access variables from my module built with requireJS?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have built a module `foo` which contains lines like:

```
MainModule.prototype = new Parent();
var bar = new MainModule();
```

the module was built with requirejs as it depended on a few other modules.

In my new module I want to be able to access some of my variables/functions in foo because they expose services that my new model wants access to so like:

```
require(["foo"], function(foo){
  console.log(foo, MainModule, bar)
})
```

I get `"undefined"` when i do this...i'm guessing it has to do with the fact that the variables `MainModule` and `bar` have been uglified in the build step. How can I prevent this from happening? Is there a way to specify variable names that must be preserved?

Answer (score 3):

Well, I'm not sure how foo is structured but MainModule and bar are probably local variables within foo.  You could return them from foo such as:

```
define(function(require) {
    var MainModule = require('MainModule');
    var bar = new MainModule();
    var someFunction = function() {
        console.log('bar');
    };

    return {
        bar: bar,
        someFunction: someFunction
    }
});
```

And then you'll have access to the data returned:

```
require(["foo"], function(foo) {
    console.log(foo.bar);
    console.log(foo.someFunction());
})
```

Comment: thanks will try to work of this. Why do you say MainModule = require('MainModule')? In my code MainModule is new Parent() where Parent is some other module. Also is passing in require a shortcut for passing in an array of dependencies as the first argument?

Comment: OK so my problem is the minification...is it impossible to make minified modules?

Answer (score 0):

The problem in the question has nothing to do with minification because the code shown in the question *cannot* work, with or without minification.

The issue is that the values that should be accessible outside the module must be exported. And outside the module they are accessible through the variable to which this module is bound by a `require` or `define` function.

To export values, you can return them from the factory function that is passed to `define`. (There are also other means to do this but I'm not going to get into them now.) Your `foo.js` file could be like this:

```
define(function () {

function Parent() {
}

function MainModule() {
}

MainModule.prototype = new Parent();
var bar = new MainModule();

// Here I'm exporting the values I want accessible outside.
return {
    MainModule: MainModule,
    bar: bar
};

});
```

I've obviously had to fill `foo.js` with the minimum amount of code to have something that would work.

Then you could have an `index.html` like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/xhtml; charset=utf-8"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/require.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      require.config({
          baseUrl: "./js",
      });
      require(["foo"], function(foo){
          console.log(foo, foo.MainModule, foo.bar)
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and `foo.js` and RequireJS located in the `js` subdirectory (relative to `index.html`), you'll see on the console that `foo`, `foo.MainModule`, and `foo.bar` are defined. The `require` call loads the module named `foo`, which resolves to `js/foo.js` and binds the value returned by the module's factory to the first argument of the callback passed to `require`. In this case the name of this argument is `foo`. So in the callback,

- `foo` is the *whole module*,
- `foo.MainModule` has the value that `MainModule` has in the module `foo`.
- `foo.bar` has the value that `bar` has in the module `foo`.

The last two bindings exist only because the module `foo` exports its values as shown above.